# Cannot center image

Tags: javascript, html, css

My image wont center either will any text when I use the center tool in both CSS and HTML it tends to just stay close to the Top left hand corner if anyone has Ideas on what to do please let me know. also I followed a video tutorial on a vertical nav bar so maybe that is interfering with centering my elements that I would like centered

```css
body, html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.logo{
  float: right;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #000000;
  transform: translate3d(-200px, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

.active-nav nav{
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 35px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.nav-toggle-btn {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

active-nav .content {
  transform: translate3d(200px, 0, 0);
}

video {
  position: absolute;
     z-index: 0;
     background: url(mel.jpg) no-repeat;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px; /* fixed to left. Replace it by right if you want.*/
     min-width: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
}

.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<doctype.html>

  <head>
    <title> LAP Aerial Photography </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="overlay">

  <header>
    <nav>
      <a href="#" class="nav-toggle-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i>Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Gallary</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>

<div class="logo">
<img src="Final_Logo.png" alt="LAP Aerial Photography">
</div>

</div>
  </header>
</div>


  <video autoplay="true" loop="true">
    <source src="Background.mov" type="video/mov">
    <source src="Background.webm" type="video/webm">
  </video>




  <footer>
  </footer>



  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var bodyEl = $('body'),
    navToggleBtn = bodyEl.find('.nav-toggle-btn');
   navToggleBtn.on('click' , function(e) {
      bodyEl.toggleClass('active-nav');
      e.preventDefault()
    });

  })();
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Your doctype declaration is incorrect. `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [Guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)! It is well-explained and clear.

EDIT:

I’ve used CSS-transformations to center the image, because flexbox is’t supported in old browsers:

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I hope the following code will help you.

```js
(function() {
    var bodyEl = $('body'),
    navToggleBtn = bodyEl.find('.nav-toggle-btn');
   navToggleBtn.on('click' , function(e) {
      bodyEl.toggleClass('active-nav');
      e.preventDefault()
    });

})();
```

```css
body, html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#logo > img {
  /* center image */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* nav */

nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #000000;
  transform: translate3d(-200px, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

.active-nav nav{
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 35px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.nav-toggle-btn {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

active-nav .content {
  transform: translate3d(200px, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>LAP Aerial Photography</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <a href="#" class="nav-toggle-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden></i></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden></i>Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden></i>About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden></i>Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden></i>Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden></i>Gallary</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <div id="logo">
        <img src="Final_Logo.png" alt="LAP Aerial Photography">
      </div>
    </header>
  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. Either form your own answer or delete this altogether. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I’m new here. Thank you for the information. I’ll fix that.